# How to access other classes methods within a class (PHP)

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm building a PHP OOP MVC Framework for personal use.

I'd like to know if there's a way or the correct implementation of the following:

Being able to call a method from a "subclass" (not extended) to another "subclass". I mean...
I have a class that creates new objects for each subclass instead of using inheritance. Let's call it MainClass, and it has 3 "SubClasses" like this

```
class MainClass {
    public $db;
    public $forms;
    public $pagination;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new class_db();
        $this->forms = new class_forms();       
        $this->utils = new class_utils();
    }   
}
```

And the initialization which is

```
$MainClass = new MainClass();
```

I can do for example

```
$MainClass->utils->show_text("Hello World");
```

And works fine.

What I'd like to do is... within the $MainClass->utils->test() (Another test method), is to be able to access $MainClass->db without using global or $GLOBALS.

Is there any alternative way of achieving this? To be able to access $MainClass methods and submethods within another submethod (access db from utils and from the main page where MainClass is initialized)? How would it be? I want to be able to access al the submethods, like utils being able to access db and forms method. as well as the pages that are outside MainClass.

Thank you

Comment: Add "Dependency Injection" to your searching for existing answers for some ideas perhaps.

Comment: Inject your MainClass instance into the vfw_constructor using `$this->utils = new vfw_utils($this);` when you instantiate it.... modify the vfw_utils constructor to set that argument as a property, et voilà

Answer (score 2):

If `utils` has to use `db`, you either have to pass the MainClass instance to utils, so it can call `$this->myRefToMain->db`, or pass the instance of `db` itself, so utils can call `$this->db`. Either way, it cannot (reasonably) crawl up the call stack to find the object that called it.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I actually was doing it, but instead of passing it to the constructor, I've made another method on the subclasses call loadFramework() and then on the MainClass call loadFramework() of all the subclasses. I didn't know if it was right. But yours it's much better code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Object if your class `class_utils` can exists without `MainClass`. And its method `test()` should access some object `db` of class `class_db`. This means `class_utils` depends on `class_db` and you should inject object of `class_db` in constructor, for example:

```
class MainClass {
    public $db;
    public $forms;
    public $pagination;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new class_db();
        $this->forms = new class_forms();       
        $this->utils = new class_utils($this->db);
    }   
}
```